# FFmpeg: How can I use the scale_vulkan filter?

Tags: ffmpeg

I did some googling on how to use the scale_vulkan filter and about Vulkan on ffmpeg, but it appears there's only a few support threads that are hard to decipher, and there isn't much documentation for Vulkan on FFmpeg. Anyway, I tried two different commands hoping the filter would work:

- `ffmpeg -hide_banner -init_hw_device vulkan=gpu:0 -filter_hw_device gpu -i "input.mkv" -filter_complex "[0:V:0]hwupload,scale_vulkan=1920:1080:bilinear:yuv420p,hwdownload,format=yuv420p[out]" -map "[out]" "output.mkv" -y`
- `ffmpeg -v verbose -init_hw_device vulkan=vul,linear_images=1 -i "input.mkv" -vf "hwupload,scale_vulkan=w=1920:h=1080:format=yuv420p,hwdownload,format=yuv420p" "output.mkv" -y`

But I got the same error message:

```
[AVHWDeviceContext @ 0000029c32857e80] No memory type found for flags 0x2
[hwupload @ 0000029c40ea5bc0] Failed to upload frame: -22.
Error while filtering: Invalid argument
Failed to inject frame into filter network: Invalid argument
Error while processing the decoded data for stream #0:0
[libvorbis @ 0000029c340afb40] 39 frames left in the queue on closing
Conversion failed!
```

Also, I don't really know how the filter works or if any particular hardware (perhaps certain GPUs) may be needed for it.

**Edit:** The specs of my Windows laptop include an AMD Ryzen 5 4500U which supports the `h264_amf` and `hevc_amf` encoders, and an Nvidia MX350 (which does NOT support NVENC).

Comment: Try using FFmpeg **version 5.0.1-full_build-www.gyan.dev**. In my machine, using Windows 10 and NVIDIA GeForce GTX 1650 the following command works: `ffmpeg -v verbose -init_hw_device vulkan=vul -i "input.mkv" -vf "hwupload,scale_vulkan=w=1920:h=1080:scaler=bilinear:format=yuv420p,hwdownload,format=yuv420p" "output.mkv" -y`. You may also try updating your GPU drivers.

Comment: It didn't work, I got the same error message and my GPU drivers are up to date.

Comment: Can you please edit your question, and add information like OS type, hardware configuration, FFmpeg version?

Comment: I edited the post to include specs of my computer, and I had tried the build on gyan.dev under "version: 5.0.1" that says "ffmpeg-release-full.7z" which didn't work.

Comment: You may try `vulkan=gpu:1` instead of `vulkan=gpu:0`. But It probably not going to work. When I use `vulkan=gpu:1`, I am getting error "No memory type found for flags 0x2", because it tries to use Vulkan on Intel HD Graphics GPU (instead of NVIDIA GPU). You may also try using CUDA acceleration with `scale_npp`.

Comment: In my case the output file is empty with no errors on ffmpeg terminal, don't know what to do. FFMPEG 5.1.2